# What's Azure equivalent of EventBridge working with CloudWatch to consume all alerts?

Tags: amazon-web-services, azure, monitoring

We're trying to find a way to be notified and consume (using logic apps) all alerts generated via Azure Monitor.

It seems that [AWS](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2019/10/amazon-cloudwatch-sends-alarm-state-change-events-amazon-eventbridge/) allows that via EventBridge, so:

"Amazon EventBridge now integrates with Amazon CloudWatch so that when CloudWatch alarms are triggered, a 
matching EventBridge rule can execute targets. "

We would like to run a logic app every time alert is triggered, so far it seems possible only via configuring additional action for alert, but we are looking for a solution that covers everything and is not so tedious to configure.

So far we've tried EventHubs, sending diagnostic data LogAnalytics, but either it's not the way or we can't configure it properly.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We've found it, the holi grail is [Action rules](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/platform/alerts-action-rules), it allows to act upon alerts from defined scope or resources via suppression or additional actions, it's on top of existing alerts, all is working as usual plus what is defined in actions.